# How can i frame a query for this

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table like this:

```
staffname | periods
___________________
david     |     yes
seema     |     no
raj       |     yes
seema     |     no
david     |     yes
```

Now i want the result like this:

```
staffname | periods
___________________
david     |     2
seema     |     2
raj       |     1
```

If you can understand i want the name and count, doesnt matter on value of second column.

I have tried but i'm getting duplicate rows.

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT STAFFNAME, COUNT(*) as PERIODS
   FROM TABLE
 GROUP BY STAFFNAME
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
   select staffname, count(periods) as periods from table1 
   group by staffname
```

if you want to order them like your result just add this in the end

```
    order by periods desc
```

[demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2475e/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try following code. It gives exact result as you want.

```
select staffname, count(1) as 'periods' from table1
group by staffname order by periods desc, staffname;
```

link to [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/98a79/21).

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT staffname, COUNT(*) AS periods 
    FROM first_table 
    GROUP BY staffname
    ORDER BY periods DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple,

```
SELECT staffname,COUNT(periods) AS periods
FROM TableName
Group By staffname
```